# How can I make an element appear and disappear using Jquery.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I want to do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($('.undermenu').css('display','block')){
        $('#menu').click(function(){
            $('.undermenu').css('display','none');
        });
    }
    else{
        $('#menu').click(function(){
            $('.undermenu').css('display','block');
        });
    }
});
```

This code does not work, but is there any Jquery "effect" or whatever that I can use to hide/un-hide.
For example is there and way to check whether or not display is set to none or block?
Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just use `toggle()`:

```
$('#menu').click(function() {
    $('.undermenu').toggle();
});
```

Though the reason your `if($('.undermenu').css('display','block'))` didn't work is because you set the `display` property of the element(s) to `block`, rather than *getting* the `display` property and testing it, which would be:

```
if ($('.undermenu').css('display') =='block')
```

If you really want to use an `if` to test the current display, before modifying the presentation, you'd have to do it inside of the click handler (otherwise it will only run once, on DOMReady, rather than every time):

```
$('#menu').click(function(){
    if ($('.undermenu').css('display') == 'block') {
        $('.undermenu').hide();
    }
    else {
        $('.undermenu').show();
    }
});
```

Or, if you want to risk the wrath of your colleagues, you can jazz that up a little:

```
$('#menu').click(function(){
    var undermenu = $('.undermenu');
    undermenu[undermenu.css('display') == 'block' ? 'hide' : 'show']();
});
```

References:

- [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/).
- [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/).

Comment: Thank you very much, I hope I was of some help! :)

Comment: Incidentally, if you feel your question has been answered please do consider clicking on the grey check-mark beside the answer that most helped you (not necessarily this one). If your question isn't answered please feel free to edit your question in order to address any shortcomings in the answers supplied so far. :)

Answer (score 1):

You use a setter on your condition :

```
// This line update .undermenu to display it and return true (return $('.undermenu'), so true)
if($('.undermenu').css('display','block')){
```

But you must get the value, and test

```
if($('.undermenu').css('display') === 'block'){
```

And you code conception is bad. If you do that, you test on document are ready if the .undermenu are displayed or not, and you put a function to the click trigger (to display or to hide..) but ! when your .undermenu was change, you already have the same trigger (to display or hide, and he never change)..

So you need to put your trigger for each click and test the value (displayed or not) on the trigger :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#menu').click(function(){
        if($('.undermenu').css('display') === 'block'){
           $('.undermenu').hide();
        }
        else {
           $('.undermenu').show();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

On jquery exists:

```
$("#element_id").show();

$("#element_id").hide();
```

also you can use:

```
$("#element_id").fadeIn();

$("#element_id").fadeOut();
```

This show and hide elements with fade effects.

You can query if the element is hidden:

```
if($("#element_id").is(":hidden")){
    $("#element_id").show():
}
else{
    $("#element_id").hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

```
$("div").click(function () {
    $("img").toggle("slow", function () {
    // Animation complete.
    });
});
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FQj89/

Answer (score 0):

You can put the if statement in the function so you don't repeat yourself. You can probably also use toggle(); type stuff depending on what you are doing. ---

```
$('#menu').click(function(){

    if ( $('.undermenu').is(':visible') ) {

        $('.undermenu').hide();

     else {

        $('.undermenu').show();

    }

});
```

This is a good way too, depending on what you are doing though, one may be better than the other.

`if ( $('.undermenu').css('display') === 'block' ) { // do something }`